# Use X509 Certificate in Objective-C NSURLConnection NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate handler

Tags: objective-c, ssl-certificate, nsurlconnection, webservice-client

I have a C# desktop application that I use to connect to a .NET web service that uses a certificate for authentication. I am trying to duplicate the C# desktop application on OS X using Objective-C. If I disable certificate validation in IIS everything works fine. Here is what I am doing in C#:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
                store.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, myCertName, true);
if (certCollection.Count > 0)
{
    storeCert = certCollection[0];
}
WebServiceClient client = new ServiceClient(basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress);
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = storeCert;
```

How can I duplicate this in willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge(...) method of NSURLConnection? I would like to load the cert from the keychain and not a certificate file bundled with my application. Here is what I have so far:

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace = [challenge protectionSpace];
    NSString *authenticationMethod = [protectionSpace authenticationMethod];

    if ([authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate])
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *searchDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [searchDictionary setObject:(id)kSecClassCertificate forKey:(id)kSecClass];
        [searchDictionary setObject:myCertName forKey:(id)kSecAttrLabel];
        [searchDictionary setObject:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(id)kSecReturnRef];
        //[searchDictionary setObject:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(id)kSecReturnData];

        NSData *queryResult = nil;
        OSStatus searchStatus = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)searchDictionary, (void *)&queryResult);

        if (searchStatus != errSecSuccess)
        {
            NSLog(@"Couldn't find the cert ref!");
            [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
            return;
        }

        SecIdentityRef identity = (__bridge SecIdentityRef)queryResult;

// TODO: MAKE STUFF WORK!!

        NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithIdentity:????? certificates:???? persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent];
        [challenge.sender useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
    else if ([authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
    {
        NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust];
        [challenge.sender useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
    else
    {
        [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}
```